# How can I make an AJAX request made in javascript fail on purpose in the debugger to test it?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Suppose if I wrote some code to handle the case where the AJAX request fails then how could I test it out? I was wondering if there was a way to make an AJAX request fail on purpose using the Chrome debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `network throttling` and go offline , which will fail the ajax call.